# Linking Entities with sentences

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

When an ontology is created from text consisting of a set of sentences, it can be useful to bind any given concept with all the sentences, where it is present. But that inevitably leads to a nasty duplication of sentences, when the usual Annotation is used for storing the related text.

E.g. the sentence *"Attributive language is the base language which allows: Atomic negation (negation of concept names that do not appear on the left hand side of axioms), Concept intersection, Universal restrictions, Limited existential quantification."* would need to be copied as an Annotation to the Entities: Attributive language, Language, Atomic negation, Negation, Concept names, Axiom, Concept intersection, Universal restriction, Limited existencial quantification.

What is in your opinion a good way to avoid copying the same sentence to several locations and yet to have traces from the Entity to the relevant sentences?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a named individual with an IRI and attach the sentence to it, then add a relationship from the concepts to the individual.

The individual might have a type, e.g., Sentence, but this is not necessary. Properties used can be annotation properties or data/object properties.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that looks promising. But I am not sure what you mean by the concept <-> individual relationship. One can have concepts as domain and range of a relation, then there are links between individuals which instantiate the relationship, but how is captured a link from a concept to an individual?

Comment: An individual can have a type, i.e., be an instance of a class.

Comment: @veeco this is the most obvious relationship that an individual belongs to a concept, isn't it? E.g. `Book(book1)` stating that `book1` is an instance of the concept(resp. class) `Book`

Comment: I see. But that would mess-up the ontology, as a sentence (individual) is obviously neither e.g. an instance of a Book or of most other Entities. I mean by using this approach there would be an individual (the sentence "Books are written by authors and are printed by a publisher.") which is at the same time an instance of a book, of an author, and of a publisher. This does not make much sense.

Comment: One could maybe have individuals of a Sentence concept, which do not belong to any other entity. Then any entity could reference the IRI to a Sentence individual in its seeAlso Annotation by using the IRI of the sentence. This is somewhat clumsy as it would require a working IRIs and also I could not see a complete list of related sentences at once. One would need to click on each IRI to see its related sentence.

Comment: Having to click on an IRI to see associated sentences is a GUI issue - could be overcome if the tool can be customized. Would be easier with a brand new annotation property rather than a standard one. However I thought your duplication concern was more related to non GUI tools.